# what is the meaning of the following phrases?

Tags: meaning

What does it mean "her eyes/gaze lined with silver" or "he caught a glimmer of silver in her eyes"? What is the meaning of "silver" here? I thought that it means that the person in cause is about to cry, but I'm not sure.

Comment: Context please. Without context, most metaphorical phrases are difficult to understand, unless they are very well known. I've never heard either of these phrases before.

Comment: Thank you for your question. We are looking for thoughtful, intriguing questions posed as you would ask them of an expert, including evidence that you have put effort and research into the question. Please edit to share the results of your research. Questions which lack results of research may be closed. [(more)](http://english.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)  
A dictionary or thesaurus may be quite helpful. Your question should include the results of your search. It should also explain why the results were not adequate to answer your question.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's just a clumsy attempt by the writer to "ring the changes" on...

> ***glint*** of **steel** in her eyes [191 hits in Google Books](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22glint%20of%20steel%20in%20her%20eyes%22)
>   *glint of steel in her eye* [21 hits](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22glint%20of%20steel%20in%20her%20eye%22)
>   *glint of steel in his eyes* [393 hits](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22glint%20of%20steel%20in%20his%20eyes%22)
>   *glint of steel in his eye* [63 hits](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22glint%20of%20steel%20in%20his%20eyes%22#tbm=bks&q=%22glint%20of%20steel%20in%20his%20eye%22)

...which as you can see is something of a well-worn cliche. Of course, it's always *possible* OP's writer really does have some specific ["argentine"](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/argentine) attribute in mind (perhaps she seeks wealth like a *gold-digger*, or she's ethereal like the *silvery moon*). But I think probably it's just bad writing.

Answer (score -2):

I'm not sure what exactly this refers to, but it probably doesn't refer to *ocular silvering*, a frightening and often terminal illness that I just made up. Patients suffering from the condition often visit their doctor or optometrist to ask about "a glimmer of silver" in the eyes - usually first noticed by friends or loved ones. In its early stages, the effect can be quite flattering - even beautiful - and so patients have been known to not seek treatment until it is too late.

The results can be devastating. Within three days, the eyes have silvered completely:

[image: Ocular silvering, exhibit A]
[image: Ocular silvering, exhibit B]

If not treated, facial and eventually full-body silvering will occur. This is known as the Lesser Midas Syndrome.

Fortunately, this disease does not exist and was invented for the purpose of answering this question. Unfortunately though, this means it is highly unlikely to be a useful answer. I am sorry. I have wasted your time.

Also: Some more context would be good. :)